# Trouble doing validation through jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have been searching around and do not understand why my code is not working. Even tried jsfiddle to see if it works but not happening for me.

To make things clear I am using twitter bootstrap, and did not do anything with the POST part of the form yet.

```
<div id="register">
    <form id="registerform" method="POST" action=""  accept-charset='UTF-8'>
       <fieldset>
         <legend>Register</legend> <br>
         <input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName" placeholder="First Name" maxlength="20" value=""/> <br>
         <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="create" value="Join"/>
         <a href="/"><button type="button" class="btn">Cancel</button></a>
      </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../js/jquery.validation.min.js"></script>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function () {
               var form = $("#registerform");
               var firstname = $("#firstName");                      
               var validator = form.validate({
                        rules: {
                            firstname: {
                                required: true,
                                minlength: 4
                            }
                        },
                });
     });
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: `<input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName" ...`, `rules: {
                            firstname: {` might be because case doesn't match. `firstName` vs. `firstname`

Comment: The OP unsuccessfully tried to get around that issue:  `var firstname = $("#firstName");`

Comment: @Sparky thanks for converting my comment into an answer, much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your field `name` is `firstName`, and the `rules` option takes the `name` attribute, not the `id` as you tried to do.

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/xGc79/**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var form = $("#registerform");

    var validator = form.validate({
        rules: {
            firstName: { // <-- this is the `name` attribute
                required: true,
                minlength: 4
            }
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: +1 yes you are correct. hi, long time... good to see you back

Comment: Thanks! I don't know if I have to make a new question for this but it ties into this one. So I see it validates now in jsfiddle... but how do I get it to work when I run it locally? Am i suppose to add something to it, because when I go to the local site (using webmatrix for my IDE)  I do not see any of the error messages popping up when I type in only 2 letters for example. Is it because I have to include an error handler?

Comment: @Leo, there is no reason why it wouldn't work locally unless you failed to properly include jQuery and the plugins.  See your JS error console for error messages.

Comment: @Leo, this is not proper format _when run locally_... `src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"`... add an `http` or an `https` for local operation.

Comment: Hm, I did add the http infront of it and even tried https, I have one error in my error list that mentions "Expected expression" Line 1, column 1 (but that is pointed to the <!DOCTYPE html> tag at the very top.

Comment: src="https//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript          src="../js/jquery.validation.min.js"   --- these are the two scripts I have up in that order as well

Comment: @Leo, if your scripts are properly included, the browser does not care if the page is local or online.  `"Expected expression" Line 1, column 1` is most likely something inside one of your JavaScript files as the JavaScript console generally does not show HTML issues, especially when HTML is the same online & locally.  Please start a new question for this issue.  Thanks.

Comment: @Leo, I noticed you're missing the colon here:  `src="https//ajax...`  should be `src="https://ajax...`

Answer (score 0):

The rules are case sensitive

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var form = $("#registerform");
    var firstname = $("#firstName");                      
    var validator = form.validate({
        rules: {
            firstName: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 4
            }
        },
    });

    form.submit(function(){
        if(!form.valid()){
            return false;
        }
    })
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/kv78w/)

Comment: You do not need to create a `submit` handler function because it's handled automatically by the plugin (and it has nothing to do with this problem).  See:  http://jsfiddle.net/kv78w/1/